# Can I gift an ibook to multiple recipients as a conference giveaway?

Tags: iphone, ipad, books, itunes-store, gift

I would like to gift a book listed on ibooks as a giveaway for 175 people at a European conference. Attendees all have iphones/ipads but are based across various European countries. I have all their email addresses and would email all individually but I seem to be thwarted by the fact that the destination of the purchasing store (UK) and the recipents store (various European countries./US) are not the same.
Can anyway suggest a solution?